# Algorithm to write a dictionary using thousands of words to find all anagrams for a given string with O(1) complexity

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, strings

Problem Statement:
Suppose we have a thousands of words and we need to maintain these words in a data structure in such a way that we should be able to find all anagrams for a given string.
I tried to achieve this with O(1) complexity.

I am looking for a algorithm to implement above scenario. I implemented this problem with below algo, but I feel that we can improve its complexity. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Algorithm:

Here is trick to utilise hash code, we can also use character histogram.

Step 1:Create an array of prime numbers.

```
   int primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, ...};

   We are using prime number to avoid false collisions.
```

Step 2:Create a method to calculate hash code of a word\string.

```
   int getHashCode(String str){
     int hash = 31;
     for(i =0 to length of str){
        hash = hash*primes['a' - str.charAt[i]];
     }
     return hash;
   }
```

Step 3: Now store all words in a HashMap.

```
void loadDictionary(String[] words){

  for( word from words for i = 0 to length of words)   {
     int hash  = getHashCode(word);
     List<String> anagrams = dictionary.get(hash);
     if(anagrams ! = null){
         anagrams.add(word);
     } else
        List<String> newAnagrams = new ArrayList<String>();
        newAnagrams.add(word);
        dictionary.put(hash, newAnagrams);
     }
  }
}
```

Step 4: Now here is the approach to find anagrams:

```
   int findNumberOfAnagrams(String str){
      List<String> anagrams = dictionary.get(getHashCode(str));
      return anagrams.size();
   }
```

Comment: Anagrams have the same sorted sequence of characters. I would use that.

Comment: What do you mean here by O(1) ? What is the parameter ?

Comment: To clarify Timot's question, there are two algorithms here: the precomputation done on the set of words, and the lookup of a string. There are also several parameters: the number and lengths of the words for the precomputation, and additionally the length of the string for the lookup. So when you discuss a complexity, you need to say which algorithm and look at all the parameters.

Comment: Using a hash is a good idea, but it isn't so simple. What happens if there's a hash collision?

Comment: @Timot Nothing special behind O(1). I should get all anagrams with single cycle .. like HashMap.get(string) .. or strings[10] ...I dont want to go for search.

Comment: @Giles It has intentional hash collision to club all anagrams (see hashCode method). And to avoid a false hash collision i am generating a unique hashCode for all anagrams. Like CAT, TAC, ATC should have same hashCode but not CAT and MAT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get some inspiration from the articles [The world's fastest scrabble program](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s06/www/lectures/scrabble.pdf) by Andrew W. Appel and [A Faster Scrabble Move Generation
Algorithm](http://www.ericsink.com/downloads/faster-scrabble-gordon.pdf) by Steven A. Gordon.
Both algorithms rely on a clever use of finite automata.

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497986/writing-an-algorithm-for-scrabble) on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash table (python dictionary or equivalent) in which the key is the sorted multiset of letters and the contents is all words composed of these letters.